# how to select "self" but not full compiled parent selector using scss?

Tags: sass

Now I have HTML structure like below :

```
<div class="land">

    <div class="tree">
        <div class="fruit"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="tree tree--yellow">
        <div class="tree__fruit"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and here is my scss file:

```
.land{
   @mixin colorSet{
      $self:&;

       &__fruit{
          background:red;
       }

       &--yellow{
           #{$self}__fruit{
              background:yellow;
           }
       }
   }
   .tree{
       @include colorSet();
   }

}
```

While the class ".land" and @mixin are both necessary (because I am gonna use it somewhere else);

The ideal condition is (here I use if statement to describe the condition, I guess this will be much easier to realize):

```
if (tree has the class 'tree--yellow' ){

  fruit which is belong to this tree turn yellow;

}
```

but it seems that the css is not compiled that way, it just generate

```
.land .tree-yellow .land .tree__fruit{
    background:yellow;
}
```

And what I want is :

```
.land .tree-yellow .tree__fruit{
    background:yellow;
}
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Where is `$self` coming from? Is it something provided by SCSS?

Comment: #self is just a variable I declare in the mixin, which is refered to parent selector '&'
@BenHull

Comment: you can check this article here https://css-tricks.com/using-sass-control-scope-bem-naming/       @BenHull

Comment: Right - sorry, I missed the assignment up the top. I'm used to the indented syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In Sass, `&` is short-hand for 'the current selector up to this point`, which means you'll always get all the selectors you're nested in, up to the root.

One workaround would be to have `colorSet` take the selector as an argument, rather than mixing inside the :

```
.land{
   @mixin colorSet($selector){

       #{$selector}__fruit{
          background:red;
       }

       #{$selector}--yellow{
           #{$selector}__fruit{
              background:yellow;
           }
       }

       #{$selector} {
           @content; //include content so you can further define styles 
       }
   }

   @include colorSet(.tree);

}
```

To me, this is a strong argument for minimizing nesting as much as possible (one of many). What you're expressing, if I understand it right, is: "Any fruit of a yellow tree, *which is growing on land* should be yellow". Maybe that's right, but are you anticipating trees which are not growing on land? Should "Yellow trees growing in water have blue fruits", or does that not make any sense?

If you remove the nesting, so that anything which uses `colorSet` is at the top level, the problem goes away.

Comment: Nice Solution :D